# How to set first order keys which are unique names in mongodb as id, during import of json file

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

```
[{
 "lk":{
       "car":"red",
       "house":"green"
       },
 "nm":{
       "car":"yellow",
       "house":"blue"
       },
 "rn":{
       "car":"cyan",
       "house":"brown"
       }
}]
```

Above is the data in json file, I want to import this data to mongodb with first order unique keys
i.e, "lk",  "nm", "rn" as the id.

So My expected import is

```
{"_id":"lk",
 "car":"red",
 "house":"green"
}
```

Now my data after import from is like this

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "60a8bf4e5afb48c03a063bab"
},
"SJ_Center_1922": {
    "20-4-2021": {
        "lobby": {
            "-Ma706vbb9ZZriiRFW6Y": "12:24:26"
        },
        "hall": {
            "-Ma7096KOM6mn1ellHAt": "12:24:35",
            "-Ma70KBxiuVJfwv-1YGH": "12:25:20"
        }
    },
    "21-4-2021": {
        "lobby": {
            "-MaBacB5VBAjAyNynJci": "9:46:46",
            "-MaC9obPzyUfnUNxWyJz": "12:24:55",
            "-MaCAH_cs0Af2nDF_Gtg": "12:26:57"
        },
        "hall": {
            "-MaBaccDC_7RBacIlVOk": "9:46:48",
            "-MaBhwZtVqMgX4-p8ZxL": "10:18:45",
            "-MaC8ZGiCKHxGv_-kLUQ": "12:19:25",
            "-MaC9pNHMfxDpMMgtvgo": "12:24:58",
            "-MaCAI1DyEo87XhOIaq_": "12:26:59"
        }
    }
}
```

}

I want to make "SJ_Center_1922" as id because that part is unique in all entries, so that I can query to extract data easily
Or If there is a better way to make sense of such data, please suggest

Comment: can you post your expected import?

Comment: I have edited with expected result